# Can you cast a repeated field without unnesting?

Tags: google-bigquery

Imagine a table called `orders` with a repeated and nested field called `items`. This field is an array of structs, where the structs contain a single field, `unit_price`. Is there a way to cast this field from a string to a float without unnesting/aggregating as I do currently?

In this case, I'm transforming a table that is created via an ETL job. The ETL job doesn't always get the data types correct, so sometimes I need to cast fields inside repeated record.

Here's my current approach:

```
SELECT
  ARRAY
  (
    SELECT AS STRUCT
    CAST(unit_price AS FLOAT64) AS unit_price
    FROM UNNEST(items)
  ) AS items
FROM orders
```

Comment: if you can explain why - this can help us to help you :o)

Comment: Edited to add motivation.

Comment: but why not using unnesting as in your current approach? any specific reason?

Comment: Ah! Just wondering if there was a simpler way... and not sure if the `UNNEST` has performance implications or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot CAST repeated field / ARRAY into array of different type
So, converting of `ARRAY<STRUCT<unit_price STRING>>` into `ARRAY<STRUCT<unit_price FLOAT64>>` will not work

I think, the way you do now is the way to go!

Note: if you were to change the name of item from `unit_price` to let's say `item_price` - below simple casting would  work

```
#standardSQL
SELECT CAST(items AS ARRAY<STRUCT<item_price STRING>>) items
FROM `project.dataset.orders`
```